# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Navigation Menu Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

I am using twitter bootstrap for my site.The navbar link get active on click but i want same effect when i scroll to particular section of the page. i.e (links turns grey on click, i want same effect when i scroll on that section)

// jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});


 $('.nav li a').on('click', function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });


});
```

I have tried using twitters **scrollspy** but because of this line of code **scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50** i am having some problem. Example When i click on Contact it goes on contact section but portfolio link is active in navigation menu.

**My Site:** www.nakibmomin.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are better solutions, but it works.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var ma = [];
    if(!$('html,body').is(':animated')){
        $('body>div[id]').each(function(i,o){
            ma.push({ i:$(o).attr('id'), p:$(o).position().top + $(o).outerHeight()});
        });
        for(m in ma){
            f = ma[m];
            if (f.p >= $(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height()/3){
                $('.menu>li.active').removeClass('active');
                $('.menu>li>a[href=#'+f.i+']').parents('li').addClass('active');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: this works perfect on scrolling but when i click on for example About Me the home link blink.....if i click on skills about me blink

Comment: with is(':animated') you can check if the other animation is in progress. i modified the script.

Answer (score 2):

Try apply `offset` of `-60` for scrollspy, to apply offset too. [From here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, do something like this:

1. Add global function to detect element visibility ([Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)):

   ```
   function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
   {
       var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
       var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

       var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
       var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

       return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
   }
   ```
2. Then attach scroll listener:

   ```
   $(window).scroll(function(){

     if(window.isScrolledIntoView('#portfolio')){
         $('.menu li').removeClass('active')
         $('[href="#portfolio"]').parent().addClass('active');
      }

   });
   ```